# Access Internal URL while using External URL

Tags: php, vnc-server

I am developing an interface to show what VNC-web stations are active and providing a link to that web interface.

Example: Station 1 is: http://192.168.1.1 on port 5800

If I run this on my local network it works fine, since all the computers are on that local network, what I need is a way to have this work from an external IP.

Is there anyway to redirect the session to a frame or something that keeps it local?

Here is a test I made that works fine on the local network, remotely it works only half-way:

`$station1 = @fsockopen("192.168.1.1", 5800);`

```
if ($station1) {
    echo "<a href='http://192.168.1.1:5800'>Station 1 active.</a>";
    echo "<br />";
        fclose($station1);
    } else {
        echo "Station 1 is inactive.";
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

'fsockopen' returns TRUE since it is executed 'server side' but clicking on the resulting link fails since it is executed on the 'client side' e.g. browser

Any way to work around this? Any ideas?

Comment: What web server are you using?  If it's apache, do you have mod_proxy enabled?

Comment: Can't you use a local station that has a public IP that works as the "server" for your app ?

Comment: $station1 will always return true if you suppress the error @

Comment: mway - Thank you for the nudge in the right direction, I will look into mod_proxy for my apache server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set up [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in your router, and have VNC run on a different port on every machine. It might be wisest to map the port number to the internal IP, for example:

```
 Port 5801 -> 192.168.1.1
 Port 5802 -> 192.168.1.2
 Port 5803 -> 192.168.1.3
 etc.
```

if you then call the page from the outside (e.g. using a dynamic IP), you'll have to find out your dynamic IP from within PHP (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966527/dynamically-get-outgoing-ip-address-with-php) for how to do that), and then link to each port.

```
<a href="123.123.123.123:5801">Station 1 active.</a>
<a href="123.123.123.123:5802">Station 2 active.</a>
<a href="123.123.123.123:5803">Station 3 active.</a>
```

there is no way to do this without mapping VNC to different ports. To an outside IP, only one IP address exists. The LAN's internal IPs are meaningless, and unreachable to a caller from the outside.

Comment: Thank you Very much Pekka, this is the way to go on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to test, (your get an error telling you whats wrong):
also accessing your WAN ip from inside the network using the WAN ip to connect to the internet cant be done with normal routers you would have to determine if its localnetwork or WAN network then change the ip accordingly (plus route all WAN traffic to the server).

```
    <?php
if(substr($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], -3)=="1.1"){$server=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];}else{$server='123.123.YOUR.WAN123.123'}
    $fp = fsockopen($server, 5800, $errno, $errstr);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='http://'.$server.':5800'>Station 1 active.</a>";
        fclose($fp);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could perhaps make a web call to http://www.whatismyip.com/ and scrape the external IP address and then use that... however that only works if the webserver is the one you are querying.  If not it gets tricky... and depending on the routing it can get really tricky... so if each internal IP has a different external IP then ok it might work but if not then you have to have control over how the requests get routed...

So say you have

192.168.1.1

192.168.1.2

192.168.1.3

and they are connected to your home wireless router which is connected to the internet.... via say your cable modem then all 3 would have the same IP to folks outside your network and in fact most likely your router wouldn't allow folks to call back into your network.  You would have to configure your router to forward requests to various ports to go to specific internal IP addresses.

So without knowing how this routing is setup answering this question is very difficult